# Just for learning, should I write my own framework without any components or tools, or just read the source code of an open source framework?

Tags: php, frameworks

I want to understand how frameworks work. Should I make my own framework from scratch without using any open source components or any tools like Composer or PHPUnit .. etc. or just read the source code of an open source framework like Symfony or Laravel .. etc.

And should I try not to use Composer and PHPUnit (For autoloading and testing)? Will that help me in the learning process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question for you - why do you want to do this and how much PHP do you know?

A framework is a tool to do something quickly - the idea is that is abstracts away something (boring and mundane stuff) so you can be more productive - in other words, the idea is you don't need to know how it works or why it works - just that it makes your life easier.

The good frameworks are relatively lightweight in so much as they do not make your page slower while, at the same time, increasing the development throughput.

Now obviously, you need to know about the framework in order to use it, but you don't need to know how it works *in detail*, and i guess this is where my question to you sits - why bother learning this unless you were planning on making your own framework or going to significantly customize another - is that your plan?

Regardless, if your underlying goal is to learn more about PHP, you do not need to look into frameworks.

Now, as this is stack overflow - instead of me asking questions in an answer - i am going to actually answer the question:

The first part of your question *"I want to understand how frameworks work"* I think is something I have addressed above - why bother? Learn PHP through projects, not through frameworks.

The next part, *"Should I make my own framework from scratch"* - here is a general programming question for you, if you were asked to go fetch some data from a web service, would yo go and write the socket layer first, then write the negotiation protocols for encryption, then write the string handling functions etc. - probably not - you would use a library (curl?) instead, why? because you know it works, and it will be better than anything you make - and it will save you time. Now, the same is true of something like a PHP framework - if you believe you can do better than the peer reviewed open source frameworks out there - then go right ahead and give it a shot, however it is unlikely that you will be topping the charts against Cake, Laravel etc. any time soon.

(a note here - there is an instance where you might want to make your own framework if you have a super specific problem that none of the existing general purpose frameworks solve, however this is unlikely)

I am going to rephrase the last part of your question to make it blindingly obvious - instead of *And should I try not to use Composer and PHPUnit (For autoloading and testing)? Will that help me in the learning process?* I think you are asking, in the generic sense - **"I want to do a PHP project, should I use quality of life tools like Composer and PHPUnit to make my life easier"** - the answer is of course yes, but only if this is a real project, there is no point in creating a proper project structure if you are doing this for a week and then going to drop it.

I would suggest you also think about using Gulp with Browser Sync - [read this](http://fettblog.eu/php-browsersync-grunt-gulp/), it will make your life so much easier with ALL php projects, not just this one (as you will have some kind of frontend output)

Anyway, i hope this gives you food for thought :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the specifics of PHP, but if you want to learn how frameworks work, you should definitely try building one yourself!

As to whether you should implement the components yourself, you'll have to choose some level of abstraction that you won't go any lower than. (Unless you're building the computer from scratch right out of transistors all the way up to the level of your framework, which would be silly). There's no harm in using open source components. Reinventing the wheel is good if you want to learn, but that doesn't mean you can't use premade spokes. Besides, you can always look at the components to see how they work anyway.